# Question closed as duplicate when it's not

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

I asked this question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087287/restoring-game-state

As it happens, I found out the answer to this question and my question is NOT answered by the so called "duplicate".

Can someone please re-open this? Clearly, the answer is that it does actually restore the state automatically and not what is written in the duplicate.

Thank you.

Comment: If it's closed by Jeff Atwood, I don't fancy your chances.

Comment: If you really want the question to be re-opened, the best thing to do is edit your original question and explain ***why*** it is not a duplicate. Telling us that the original doesn't answer your question doesn't mean it's not a duplicate. You need to draw a precise distinction between the question you're asking, and the question being asked in the duplicate question.

Comment: @Andrew: I've heard nothing but bad things about Jeff Atwood even though I've never even had direct contact with him. I'm not bothered about the question anymore since I have the complete and correct answer.

Comment: Saying that is like walking into a Tom Hanks fan club meeting and saying loudly "I've heard that Tom Hanks is a jerk."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have *no* idea about the details, but the accepted answer to the other question being the wrong answer to your question does not exclude that your question is a duplicate. Maybe it just happens that you have a better (or more up-to-date) answer to that duplicate? (Let me point out that I know nothing about iPhones!)

Answer (score 4):

Jeff might not be an iOS developer, but I am and this IS a duplicate.

Comment: Is it possible with the rapidly-evolving state of iOS that a *better* solution has emerged since the answer to the duplicate question was posted/accepted? If that's the case, and @Matt has figured out a better way, he should post it as an answer to the duplicate question!

Answer (score 1):

Except for the part about "Is this rumor that I only half remember, and can't find any evidence of, true?", I'm afraid it looks like a dupe to me. If you can edit it with a source for that information and turn it into a question specifically about using whatever this new technique is, then I'd be willing to cast a reopen vote. It would also be good to include a link to other, similar questions and mention the differences with your question.

The reason for closing questions as dupes is not so much that they are exactly the same problem, but that the same *solution* applies. The idea is to funnel all the solution information into one place so that it is easy to find and use.

Even in this case, where you believe you've found a better solution to the old question's problem, it might be best to do as Cody suggested under Henrik's post and add your answer to the older question.

Comment: Note that I suggested the same `:-)`

Comment: @Hendrik: Certainly; I didn't mean to suppress your answer.